# Error after using input() to get user age

Tags: python, pycharm

I for the life of me cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here's what I have so far. It's my first time trying to use PyCharm. Please help.

> PyCharm. Write a program that prompts the user for their name and
> age. Your program should then tell the user the year they were born

```
user_name = input()
user_age = input()
birth_year = (2020 - user_age)

print('Hello',user_name,'!','You were born in', birth_year)
```

PyCharm just keeps giving me this:

```
C:\Users\HELLO\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/HELLO/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py
```

Comment: FYI it you didn't paste the actual error. This code would certainly produce an error.

Comment: I never said it was an error I said this is all PyCharm keeps giving me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `input()` function function returns string by default modify it by passing it to int() funtion as follows:

```py
user_name = input()
user_age = int(input())
birth_year = (2020 - user_age)

print('Hello',user_name,'!','You were born in', birth_year)
```

Comment: Does Pycharm just eat all error messages and replace them with stating the project's directory?

Comment: No It must've shown you the error somewhere, in your case it will be `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'`. Pycharm and any other environment will give you the module's directory in case you are running multiple modules at a time so as to help you find the module with the encountered error.

Comment: It's definitely possible that I wasn't looking in the right place for an error code. As I stated this is my first time with PyCharm and since I'm learning online I really didn't get any tutorial on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to make the users age input as an integer. That way the program knows that you are trying to subtract a number, not a string, which would result in an error.